# Cannot call 'operator >=' with 'expr1'=series[bool]. The argument should be of type: const float

Tags: pine-script

```
trend= input(5, minval=1, title="Trend in Bars")

DojiSize = input(0.06, minval=0.01, title="Doji size")

data=(abs(open - close) <= (high - low) * DojiSize)

plotchar(data, title="Doji", text='Doji', color=color.white)

dojialert = (data >= 0.01) and (DojiSize <= 0.06)
```

I'm actually trying to run this code but receive the error :

```
Cannot call 'operator >=' with 'expr1'=series[bool]. The argument should be of type: const float
```

can I get some help please?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run the code, but I think the problem lies in line 3:

```
data=(abs(open - close) <= (high - low) * DojiSize)
```

It appears you are assigning the value of a comparison into something you actually wanted value from.

Try this instead...

```
data = ( abs(open - close) <= ((high - low) * DojiSize) ) ? abs(open - close) : (high - low) * DojiSize
```

Also, you must be doing something with trend, like:

```
trendEma = ema(close, trend)
```

...you can't just create a variable input with the name "trend" and expect TradingView to know what you want to do with it.

I suspect you've come from a higher-level scripting language where these things are done foe you.  With Pine Script you do more of the coding yourself (then most of it will be trying to find workarounds for annoying limitations and bugs in the language!).