# Pine script error: "Cannot call 'operator ==' with 'expr1'=plot. The argument should be of type: const bool;"

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to utilize a public indicator on tradingview, and wanted to make a backtest strategy out of the tweaked code. I currently struggle with working around the following error:

"*Compilation error. Line 149: Cannot call 'operator ==' with 'expr1'=plot. The argument should be of type: const bool;*"

The error comes from the following piece of the code (*the script is written on version4 of pine*):

```
if (plot(rx[1]) == true) //error comes here 
    rx = true
else
    rx = false

if (plot(rd[1]) == true)  // & error comes here 
    rd= true
else
    rd= false
```

Any ideas on how to approach & solve this issue? Thank you in advance!

I tried the following [solution provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68782789/cannot-call-operator-with-expr1-seriesbool-the-argument-should-be-of-t) on the same error message but the error just switched to another one. Currently the strategy sits as not compiled because of the error above, but seems like the rest of the code has no issues.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with `plot(rx[1]) == true` and `plot(rd[1]) == true`?

Answer (score 0):

in Pinescript, plot is a plot object, not a boolean.
So you can't compare your 'plot' with a boolean.
That's why you get the error

You must compare a boolean with a boolean, or a plot with a plot.